# Об именах Егор и Георгий

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Моя мама 1917 г. р. - Егоровна, после регистрации брака при обмене паспорта (фамилии) её отчество написали Георгиевна. Можно ли как-то документально подтвердить, что Егор и Георгий - это одно и то же имя. Если да, то как?

Comment: А  зачем  ей  это  сейчас-то  уже ?  Или  она  недавно  замуж  вышла ?

Comment: Мне когда-то, много лет назад, в местном ЗАГСе выдали справку, что Егор и Георгий — одно и то же имя.

Answer (score 1):

Если зайти в **"Православный календарь"** на имена мужские по букве Е ([link text](http://days.pravoslavie.ru/ABC/me.htm)), то имя ЕГОР или что-то похожее там отсутствует - т. е. это имя не есть православное каноническое. В то же время  **Егоры** на Руси были во множестве испокон веку, когда православие господствовало во всех сферах общественной жизни и неканонические имена просто не признавались церковью. То есть церковь неканонические имена принципиально не воспринимала; сохранилась запись XVII века о неком казаке Богдане: *"Казак Богдан, а имя ему бог весть..."*, то есть Богдан считалось не именем, а прозвищем, кличкой. Не случайно крещенные в православие казаки еврейско-хазарского происхождения имели два имени: семейно-национальное и крестильное; например: Стенька /=Стенек/ Разин в крещении Степан, Ермак /=Иеремия/ Тимофеевич в крещении Василий, Богдан Хмельницкий в крещении Зиновий.

Что касается имени *Богдан*, то оно ошибочно считается славянским (=бог-ом дан), а в действительности оно еврейское - среди евреев полно Богдановых, Богдановичей, Богдановских и т. п.  Российский генерал Барклай-де-Толли, сын шотландского дворянина, звался Михаил **Богданович**, - откуда у его отца-шотландца могло взяться имя *Богдан*, если оно славянское? Зато еврейские имена у британцев были в ходу со времён рыцарей-тамплиеров.

Теперь перейдём к имени ЕГОР, которое **всегда считалось вполне легитимным**, дублем канонического имени ГЕОРГИЙ. **Почему церковь признавала имя ЕГОР?** Всё дело в том, что первые христианские святые были диаспорными евреями и носили еврейские имена. Христианство первоначально было сектой в рамках иудаизма, и исследователи называют этот период иудеохристианством. Даже тот, кто, не будучи евреем, обращался ко Христу, первоначально должен был обратиться в иудаизм с переменой имени на иудейское, а уже потом допускался к крещению. Это уже впоследствии греко-византийские и латинские редакторы переиначивали имена первых святых на греческий лад и корректировали их жития. Ранее я уже писал об этом в других *ОТВЕТАХ*. Имя ЕГОР суть наглядный пример такой переделки. Первоисходник ивритный - ЕГОР, а греческая переделка - ГЕОРГИЙ (в пер. с греч. земледелец). Но народная память (возможно, со времён хазар) сохранила ивритный первоисходник, и ЕГОР вполне легитимно употреблялся как первоначальная форма имени святого Георгия Победоносца.

Зайдём в "Электронную книгу памяти воинов-евреев..." ([link text](http://jmemory.org/)), нажмём на графу *Мемориал*, внизу страницы в алфавитном указателе выберем **Ег** и увидим среди подтверждённых евреев фамилии Егоров, Егоренко, Егоренков. Посмотрим и на **Иг** - увидим Игор и Игрон. То же самое с именем *Ефим*, которое у евреев ходовое имя, но также и у русских издревле было широко распространено в народе. А ведь в **Православном календаре** нет такого имени и святого *Ефима* (проверьте по той же ссылке), зато есть имя и святой *Евфимий* /Е-В-Ф -имий) - суть греческая переделка еврейского *Ефима*. То есть ЕГОР и ГЕОРГИЙ - это то же самое, что ЕФИМ и ЕВФИМИЙ, - ивритный первоисходник и греческая переделка.

След еврейского первоисходного имени можно увидеть и в сопоставлении русских и украинских имён. В России - *Афанасий*, в Украине - *Панас*. А ивритный первоисходник - *Апониц*(*с*) /ивритная буква *пей* **פ** озвучивается двояко П и Ф /; в др./русской летописной повести сохранилась личность верного слуги рязанского князя Федора (убитого по приказу Батыя) по имени Апоница (возможно он был хазаром по происхождению). А вот староодесский бандит Мишка *Япончик* (есть и современный уголовник-подражатель): *Япончик* - это не Япония, а еврей *Апониц*. Украинский Панас и русский Афанасий - это два варианта воспроизведения ивритного оригинала *Апониц*/*Афониц* (П=Ф). То же самое с русской *Ксенией*, украинской *Оксаной* и белорусской (а также казачье-донской) *Аксиньей*. Таким образом, мы убеждаемся по имени ЕГОР в существовании и живучести ивритного именного первоисходника наряду с официальной православной канонической греческой переделкой имени святого Георгия Победоносца.

Comment: Уважаемый Следопыт,  ваша  версия  происхождения  прозвища  Мишки  Япончика  очень  интересна.  Но  есть  ли  у  неё  какие-либо  документальные  потверждения ?  Или,  хотя  бы,  письма,  воспоминания  уроженцев  старой  Одессы.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не совсем понятна ситуация (когда все это произошло, жива ли мама, когда менялся паспорт, для какой цели вообще нужно что-то доказывать), но если отвечать вопрос так, как он поставлен, то нет. **Доказать то, что это одно и то же имя невозможно, поскольку для ЗАГСов, судов и вообще гражданских (не церковных) учреждений это разные имена.**

Уточните, в чем суть проблемы, возможно решение лежит в другой плоскости. 
Если, скажем, речь идет об установлении родственных связей (а другой ситуации я что-то сразу и не придумаю), то вполне реально решить все  на основании суда, которые своим решением установит, что документы выданные на имя такой-то считать выданными на другое имя. *Разумеется, это не значит, что "имя одно и то же", ибо это будет решение по частному случаю и конкретному документу*. Как вам верно сказали, потребуется документальное подтверждение, хотя "документами" могут быть признаны не только государственные документы, для суда в принципе годятся фотографии, личные письма, свидетельские показания. 
Но тут надо нормального юриста подключать, только учтите, что дело это небыстрое и дорогое - соизмеряйте цель и средства.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, у вас мало шансов. Нужны именно документы, например наградные листы с медалями, Почетные грамоты, книжки сберегательные, пропуска или удостоверения, свидетельство о рождении, аттестат и пр. Все, что до времени вступления в брак.

Иначе - выписки из домовых книг, выписка из органа регистрации брака, а еще лучше свидетели, коих с 17-го года рождения наверняка-то и в живых нет.

Это не одно и то же имя, формально.

У меня есть родственница, мучается с фамилией, ПОНОМАР**Е**ВА, ПОНОМАР**Ё**ВА. Будь она неладна, бюрократия.

Comment: Узаконте  букву  Ё  и  ударение  сделайте  обязательным  на  письме,  хотя  бы  для  имён  собственных - и  не  страшна  нам  никакая  бюрократия.

Comment: Узаконьте букву Ё и ударение сделайте обязательным на письме!

Comment: Сейчас, вроде, уже признали, что ФИО с Е и Ё в документах считать идентичными. Но трясти работников всяких там собесов все равно приходится.

Answer (score 0):

Уже нельзя, так как эти (и Юрий) давно вышли из Георгия и столетиями были отдельными именами. Как и не только они.